# Python unexpected EOF while parsing while reading input from a text file

Tags: python, parsing, eof

I have the following code where I read data from text file and output results. Everything works until the 20th text file after which point i get the error:

```
>>> %Run read_file_test.py
File "<unknown>", line 0

^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

There is nothing different on my 20th test file compared to 19, 18 or 17...1. It just happens to be longer in length. The error I believe happens on the print statement.

```
def unitTests():
    tests=["test0.txt","test1.txt","test2.txt","test3.txt","test4.txt", "test5.txt","test6.txt","test7.txt", "test8.txt","test9.txt","test10.txt",
       "test11.txt","test12.txt","test13.txt","test14.txt","test15.txt","test16.txt","test17.txt","test18.txt","test19.txt","test20.txt"]

    for test in tests:
        with open(test) as unit:
            input = unit.read()
            data=[s.strip() for s in input.splitlines()]
            graph=[]
            for i in data:
                graph.append(ast.literal_eval(i))
            print(len(graph[1]),"\t",brute_force_vertex_cover(graph[0], graph[1], 15))#,"\t",(function(graph[0], graph[1], 15)))
     print("done")
unitTests()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't your error coming from `last.literal_eval(i)`? Have you checked the content of your file and what's inside `data`?

Comment: you could try printing the `repr(i)` before calling `literal_eval`, and see where it fails.  otherwise just print it if you get an exception

Comment: Just looked at literal_eval(i) looks like thats where I had the bug. Turns out I had an extra space on Test20.txt captured that wasn't easy to see. Thanks for all the help!